# CSS media queries, ignore property on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have a certain CSS class which holds `width` property with value set to:

`calc(100% - 17px)`

Now I want to completely ignore this property for devices with specific resolution, I tried applying media queries and using `initial`, `inherit` and `unset` as values for the `width` property. It does fix my problem to certain degree, but it still doesn't look very nice.

When I uncheck the property in Chrome styles tab everything looks great, so what would be the CSS alternative to unchecking property in Chrome styles tab ?

Comment: how about `width: auto` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instaed cancel that in some resolution set it only when you want

For example you want it from 800px and not under use:

**Mean you have to use `min-width`**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .className{
    width:calc(100% - 17px);
  }
}
```

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: I feel stupid for not even coming across that idea, let me give it a try.

Comment: You are **not** stupid :) Sometimes we have just to think out of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore that with the following code:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .elem{
    width: unset;
  }
}
```

In this code, the width of `.elem` element set `unset` when the resolution is less than 768px

Comment: As I already stated in my question, I have already tried that.